# Rest Service that returns table rows with Embedded element from MongoDB using Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, jpa, morphia

I am creating a rest service that hits a MongoDB, and returns the results of a query.  However, I am having some confusion about how to return the embedded elements of the query.

My Teacher Entity looks like so:

```
package org.dummy.entities;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Embedded;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Id;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Property;

@Entity("teachers")
public class Teacher {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Property("first_name")
    private String first;   

    @Property("middle_initial")
    private String middle;

    @Property("last_name")
    private String last;

    @Property("url")
    private String url;

    @Embedded("info")
    private TeacherInfo info;
}
```

My TeacherInfo Entity looks like so:

```
package org.dummy.entities;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Embedded;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Property;

@Embedded
public class TeacherInfo {
    @Property("address")
    private String address; 

    @Property("phone")
    private String phone;

    @Property("grade")
    private String grade;
}
```

And my Service to get all teachers looks like this:

```
package org.dummy.services;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.code.morphia.Datastore;
import com.google.code.morphia.Morphia;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;    
import org.dummy.entities.Teachers;
import org.dummy.entities.TeacherInfo;  

@Path("/teachers")
public class TeacherService {
    private Datastore db;
    public static final String DB_NAME = "test_db";

    @Path("/all/")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Teacher> getAllTeachers() {
        Datastore ds = getDatastore();
        return ds.createQuery(Teacher.class).asList();
    }

    private Datastore getDatastore() {
        try {
            Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
            db = new Morphia().map(Teacher.class).map(TeacherInfo.class).createDatastore(mongo, DB_NAME);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error initializing mongo db", e);
        }
        return db;
    }
}
```

On Mongo command line, if I run db.teachers.find(), I get:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5367f8b326d508614e3c4aa4"),
    "info": {
        "address": "dummy address",
        "phone":   "(555) 867-9305",
        "grade":   "K"
    },
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "middle_initial": "P",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "url": "<host>/teachers/Jane_P_Doe/"
}
```

However if I run the service I get:

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectId("5367f8b326d508614e3c4aa4"),
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "middle_initial": "P",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "url": "<host>/teachers/Jane_P_Doe/"
}]
```

I would like to get out the info as well, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by putting my elements into a DTO.